# Why do so many people put the app.run() in flask sites into a __name__ == "__main__" condition?

Tags: python, flask

I know what `if __name__ == "__main__"` does and use it, but why do so many people and the documentation put the " app.run()  "  function of flask in this condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because there are certain situation where you have to access certain variables for example when you have a sqlalchemy database and If you want create tables. You have to do

```py
from app import db
```

In such situation you app will run

Also when you move to production you don't need `run` and app is called from elsewhere if you add if `__name__ == "__main__`" part `run` will not be called unnecessarly.

Answer (score 2):

This will ensure that when this module is imported, it won't run the code within

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Your **name** == "**main**" when you run the .py directly.

ex:

```
foo.py
        import bar
        print("This is foo file)
```

now the inverse:

```
bar.py
import foo

def main():
    print(This is bar file)
    print(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

(running the bar.py file)

```
python bar.py

This is foo file
This is bar file
"__main__"
```

(running the foo.py file)

```
python foo.py

this is foo file
```

I know others will comment and provide a more thorough answer. But this is one way of looking at it.

Cheers.

Comment: I did read what you provided. The reason they put the " app.run() " method inside of condition, is so that it doesn't run, when it's not the main script. Do you disagree?   "Your name == "main" when you run the .py directly."

Comment: Yeah, but the question was why it wouldn´t be in the main script

Comment: For sure. I'll work on reading the question more attentively. Cheers man.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, because it explains everything. I think it's pretty clear, that you don't always want to run the complete script, but sometimes just use the classes and functions. This is also not a special case with flask, it is also used in GUI programming and in every proper python script. `app.run()` is just the main function of flask for their backend code. Seems like this is more an answer than a comment now.

Comment: Also, not trying to get into an argument. Trying to refine my process for future answers. Cheers.